# Convert Excel Spreadsheets to HTML using the Apache POI library

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I am trying to use ExcelToHtmlConverter class to convert a word document in HTML, but the documentation is not clear.

Does anyone have a sample program on how to load a excel document and convert it into html.

Comment: Can you confirm which file format are you trying to convert? It sounds like Excel, but your description mentions "word document" as well ..

Answer (score 15):

Did you look at this?: http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/poi/trunk/src/examples/src/org/apache/poi/ss/examples/html/ToHtml.java

```java
    /* ====================================================================
   Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one or more
   contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file distributed with
   this work for additional information regarding copyright ownership.
   The ASF licenses this file to You under the Apache License, Version 2.0
   (the "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance with
   the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at

       http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

   Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
   distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
   WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
   See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
   limitations under the License.
==================================================================== */
package org.apache.poi.ss.examples.html;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.Closeable;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.Formatter;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;

import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook;
import org.apache.poi.openxml4j.exceptions.InvalidFormatException;
import org.apache.poi.ss.format.CellFormat;
import org.apache.poi.ss.format.CellFormatResult;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.BorderStyle;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.CellStyle;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.CellType;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Font;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.HorizontalAlignment;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Sheet;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.VerticalAlignment;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Workbook;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.WorkbookFactory;
import org.apache.poi.util.IOUtils;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;

/**
 * This example shows how to display a spreadsheet in HTML using the classes for
 * spreadsheet display.
 */
public class ToHtml {
    private final Workbook wb;
    private final Appendable output;
    private boolean completeHTML;
    private Formatter out;
    private boolean gotBounds;
    private int firstColumn;
    private int endColumn;
    private HtmlHelper helper;

    private static final String DEFAULTS_CLASS = "excelDefaults";
    private static final String COL_HEAD_CLASS = "colHeader";
    private static final String ROW_HEAD_CLASS = "rowHeader";

    private static final Map<HorizontalAlignment, String> HALIGN = mapFor(
            HorizontalAlignment.LEFT, "left",
            HorizontalAlignment.CENTER, "center",
            HorizontalAlignment.RIGHT, "right",
            HorizontalAlignment.FILL, "left",
            HorizontalAlignment.JUSTIFY, "left",
            HorizontalAlignment.CENTER_SELECTION, "center");

    private static final Map<VerticalAlignment, String> VALIGN = mapFor(
            VerticalAlignment.BOTTOM, "bottom",
            VerticalAlignment.CENTER, "middle",
            VerticalAlignment.TOP, "top");

    private static final Map<BorderStyle, String> BORDER = mapFor(
            BorderStyle.DASH_DOT, "dashed 1pt",
            BorderStyle.DASH_DOT_DOT, "dashed 1pt",
            BorderStyle.DASHED, "dashed 1pt",
            BorderStyle.DOTTED, "dotted 1pt",
            BorderStyle.DOUBLE, "double 3pt",
            BorderStyle.HAIR, "solid 1px",
            BorderStyle.MEDIUM, "solid 2pt",
            BorderStyle.MEDIUM_DASH_DOT, "dashed 2pt",
            BorderStyle.MEDIUM_DASH_DOT_DOT, "dashed 2pt",
            BorderStyle.MEDIUM_DASHED, "dashed 2pt",
            BorderStyle.NONE, "none",
            BorderStyle.SLANTED_DASH_DOT, "dashed 2pt",
            BorderStyle.THICK, "solid 3pt",
            BorderStyle.THIN, "dashed 1pt");

    @SuppressWarnings({"unchecked"})
    private static <K, V> Map<K, V> mapFor(Object... mapping) {
        Map<K, V> map = new HashMap<K, V>();
        for (int i = 0; i < mapping.length; i += 2) {
            map.put((K) mapping[i], (V) mapping[i + 1]);
        }
        return map;
    }

    /**
     * Creates a new converter to HTML for the given workbook.
     *
     * @param wb     The workbook.
     * @param output Where the HTML output will be written.
     *
     * @return An object for converting the workbook to HTML.
     */
    public static ToHtml create(Workbook wb, Appendable output) {
        return new ToHtml(wb, output);
    }

    /**
     * Creates a new converter to HTML for the given workbook.  If the path ends
     * with "<tt>.xlsx</tt>" an {@link XSSFWorkbook} will be used; otherwise
     * this will use an {@link HSSFWorkbook}.
     *
     * @param path   The file that has the workbook.
     * @param output Where the HTML output will be written.
     *
     * @return An object for converting the workbook to HTML.
     */
    public static ToHtml create(String path, Appendable output)
            throws IOException {
        return create(new FileInputStream(path), output);
    }

    /**
     * Creates a new converter to HTML for the given workbook.  This attempts to
     * detect whether the input is XML (so it should create an {@link
     * XSSFWorkbook} or not (so it should create an {@link HSSFWorkbook}).
     *
     * @param in     The input stream that has the workbook.
     * @param output Where the HTML output will be written.
     *
     * @return An object for converting the workbook to HTML.
     */
    public static ToHtml create(InputStream in, Appendable output)
            throws IOException {
        try {
            Workbook wb = WorkbookFactory.create(in);
            return create(wb, output);
        } catch (InvalidFormatException e){
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Cannot create workbook from stream", e);
        }
    }

    private ToHtml(Workbook wb, Appendable output) {
        if (wb == null) {
            throw new NullPointerException("wb");
        }
        if (output == null) {
            throw new NullPointerException("output");
        }
        this.wb = wb;
        this.output = output;
        setupColorMap();
    }

    private void setupColorMap() {
        if (wb instanceof HSSFWorkbook) {
            helper = new HSSFHtmlHelper((HSSFWorkbook) wb);
        } else if (wb instanceof XSSFWorkbook) {
            helper = new XSSFHtmlHelper();
        } else {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                    "unknown workbook type: " + wb.getClass().getSimpleName());
        }
    }

    /**
     * Run this class as a program
     *
     * @param args The command line arguments.
     *
     * @throws Exception Exception we don't recover from.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        if(args.length < 2){
            System.err.println("usage: ToHtml inputWorkbook outputHtmlFile");
            return;
        }

        ToHtml toHtml = create(args[0], new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(args[1])));
        toHtml.setCompleteHTML(true);
        toHtml.printPage();
    }

    public void setCompleteHTML(boolean completeHTML) {
        this.completeHTML = completeHTML;
    }

    public void printPage() throws IOException {
        try {
            ensureOut();
            if (completeHTML) {
                out.format(
                        "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"iso-8859-1\" ?>%n");
                out.format("<html>%n");
                out.format("<head>%n");
                out.format("</head>%n");
                out.format("<body>%n");
            }

            print();

            if (completeHTML) {
                out.format("</body>%n");
                out.format("</html>%n");
            }
        } finally {
            IOUtils.closeQuietly(out);
            if (output instanceof Closeable) {
                IOUtils.closeQuietly((Closeable) output);
            }
        }
    }

    public void print() {
        printInlineStyle();
        printSheets();
    }

    private void printInlineStyle() {
        //out.format("<link href=\"excelStyle.css\" rel=\"stylesheet\" type=\"text/css\">%n");
        out.format("<style type=\"text/css\">%n");
        printStyles();
        out.format("</style>%n");
    }

    private void ensureOut() {
        if (out == null) {
            out = new Formatter(output);
        }
    }

    public void printStyles() {
        ensureOut();

        // First, copy the base css
        BufferedReader in = null;
        try {
            in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    getClass().getResourceAsStream("excelStyle.css")));
            String line;
            while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
                out.format("%s%n", line);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Reading standard css", e);
        } finally {
            IOUtils.closeQuietly(in);
        }

        // now add css for each used style
        Set<CellStyle> seen = new HashSet<CellStyle>();
        for (int i = 0; i < wb.getNumberOfSheets(); i++) {
            Sheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(i);
            Iterator<Row> rows = sheet.rowIterator();
            while (rows.hasNext()) {
                Row row = rows.next();
                for (Cell cell : row) {
                    CellStyle style = cell.getCellStyle();
                    if (!seen.contains(style)) {
                        printStyle(style);
                        seen.add(style);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private void printStyle(CellStyle style) {
        out.format(".%s .%s {%n", DEFAULTS_CLASS, styleName(style));
        styleContents(style);
        out.format("}%n");
    }

    private void styleContents(CellStyle style) {
        styleOut("text-align", style.getAlignmentEnum(), HALIGN);
        styleOut("vertical-align", style.getVerticalAlignmentEnum(), VALIGN);
        fontStyle(style);
        borderStyles(style);
        helper.colorStyles(style, out);
    }

    private void borderStyles(CellStyle style) {
        styleOut("border-left", style.getBorderLeftEnum(), BORDER);
        styleOut("border-right", style.getBorderRightEnum(), BORDER);
        styleOut("border-top", style.getBorderTopEnum(), BORDER);
        styleOut("border-bottom", style.getBorderBottomEnum(), BORDER);
    }

    private void fontStyle(CellStyle style) {
        Font font = wb.getFontAt(style.getFontIndex());

        if (font.getBold()) {
            out.format("  font-weight: bold;%n");
        }
        if (font.getItalic()) {
            out.format("  font-style: italic;%n");
        }

        int fontheight = font.getFontHeightInPoints();
        if (fontheight == 9) {
            //fix for stupid ol Windows
            fontheight = 10;
        }
        out.format("  font-size: %dpt;%n", fontheight);

        // Font color is handled with the other colors
    }

    private String styleName(CellStyle style) {
        if (style == null) {
            style = wb.getCellStyleAt((short) 0);
        }
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        Formatter fmt = new Formatter(sb);
        try {
            fmt.format("style_%02x", style.getIndex());
            return fmt.toString();
        } finally {
            fmt.close();
        }
    }

    private <K> void styleOut(String attr, K key, Map<K, String> mapping) {
        String value = mapping.get(key);
        if (value != null) {
            out.format("  %s: %s;%n", attr, value);
        }
    }

    private static CellType ultimateCellType(Cell c) {
        CellType type = c.getCellTypeEnum();
        if (type == CellType.FORMULA) {
            type = c.getCachedFormulaResultTypeEnum();
        }
        return type;
    }

    private void printSheets() {
        ensureOut();
        Sheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);
        printSheet(sheet);
    }

    public void printSheet(Sheet sheet) {
        ensureOut();
        out.format("<table class=%s>%n", DEFAULTS_CLASS);
        printCols(sheet);
        printSheetContent(sheet);
        out.format("</table>%n");
    }

    private void printCols(Sheet sheet) {
        out.format("<col/>%n");
        ensureColumnBounds(sheet);
        for (int i = firstColumn; i < endColumn; i++) {
            out.format("<col/>%n");
        }
    }

    private void ensureColumnBounds(Sheet sheet) {
        if (gotBounds) {
            return;
        }

        Iterator<Row> iter = sheet.rowIterator();
        firstColumn = (iter.hasNext() ? Integer.MAX_VALUE : 0);
        endColumn = 0;
        while (iter.hasNext()) {
            Row row = iter.next();
            short firstCell = row.getFirstCellNum();
            if (firstCell >= 0) {
                firstColumn = Math.min(firstColumn, firstCell);
                endColumn = Math.max(endColumn, row.getLastCellNum());
            }
        }
        gotBounds = true;
    }

    private void printColumnHeads() {
        out.format("<thead>%n");
        out.format("  <tr class=%s>%n", COL_HEAD_CLASS);
        out.format("    <th class=%s>&#x25CA;</th>%n", COL_HEAD_CLASS);
        //noinspection UnusedDeclaration
        StringBuilder colName = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = firstColumn; i < endColumn; i++) {
            colName.setLength(0);
            int cnum = i;
            do {
                colName.insert(0, (char) ('A' + cnum % 26));
                cnum /= 26;
            } while (cnum > 0);
            out.format("    <th class=%s>%s</th>%n", COL_HEAD_CLASS, colName);
        }
        out.format("  </tr>%n");
        out.format("</thead>%n");
    }

    private void printSheetContent(Sheet sheet) {
        printColumnHeads();

        out.format("<tbody>%n");
        Iterator<Row> rows = sheet.rowIterator();
        while (rows.hasNext()) {
            Row row = rows.next();

            out.format("  <tr>%n");
            out.format("    <td class=%s>%d</td>%n", ROW_HEAD_CLASS,
                    row.getRowNum() + 1);
            for (int i = firstColumn; i < endColumn; i++) {
                String content = "&nbsp;";
                String attrs = "";
                CellStyle style = null;
                if (i >= row.getFirstCellNum() && i < row.getLastCellNum()) {
                    Cell cell = row.getCell(i);
                    if (cell != null) {
                        style = cell.getCellStyle();
                        attrs = tagStyle(cell, style);
                        //Set the value that is rendered for the cell
                        //also applies the format
                        CellFormat cf = CellFormat.getInstance(
                                style.getDataFormatString());
                        CellFormatResult result = cf.apply(cell);
                        content = result.text;
                        if (content.equals("")) {
                            content = "&nbsp;";
                        }
                    }
                }
                out.format("    <td class=%s %s>%s</td>%n", styleName(style),
                        attrs, content);
            }
            out.format("  </tr>%n");
        }
        out.format("</tbody>%n");
    }

    private String tagStyle(Cell cell, CellStyle style) {
        if (style.getAlignmentEnum() == HorizontalAlignment.GENERAL) {
            switch (ultimateCellType(cell)) {
            case STRING:
                return "style=\"text-align: left;\"";
            case BOOLEAN:
            case ERROR:
                return "style=\"text-align: center;\"";
            case NUMERIC:
            default:
                // "right" is the default
                break;
            }
        }
        return "";
    }
}
```

Comment: yes but i am getting the following errors                    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at java.io.Reader.<init>(Unknown Source)
 at java.io.InputStreamReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
 at ToHtml.printStyles(ToHtml.java:215)
 at ToHtml.printInlineStyle(ToHtml.java:199)
 at ToHtml.print(ToHtml.java:192)
 at ToHtml.printPage(ToHtml.java:175)
 at ToHtml.main(ToHtml.java:156)

Comment: `ExcelToHtmlConverter` is not used in that example. Judging from the exceptions I am getting trying to convert an XLS file with it, namely `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Your InputStream was neither an OLE2 stream, nor an OOXML stream`, this example is for XLSX files, not XLS files

Comment: An actual example of usage would be nice.  I can't find an example anywhere.

Comment: how can convert `XSSFWorkbook`? this source only convert `XLS` format.

Comment: In case anyone else is looking for an example on how to use this, here's what worked for me:


`public static toHtml(File inputDocument){
        StringWriter output = new StringWriter()
        ToHtml.create(new FileInputStream(inputDocument),output).printPage()
        return output.toString()
}`

Answer (score 3):

**Required jars:**
poi-3.17.jar
poi-examples-3.17.jar
poi-excelant-3.17.jar
poi-ooxml-3.17.jar
poi-ooxml-schemas-3.15.0.jar
dom4j-1.6.1.jar
poi-scratchpad-3.17.jar
xmlbeans-2.6.0.jar

```
    /**
     * Excel to HTML
     * 
     */
    public static void excel2Html(String filename, String htmlid, String ctxPath) throws Exception{
        InputStream input=new FileInputStream(filename);
         HSSFWorkbook excelBook=new HSSFWorkbook(input);
         ExcelToHtmlConverter excelToHtmlConverter = new ExcelToHtmlConverter(DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder().newDocument());
         excelToHtmlConverter.processWorkbook(excelBook);
         List pics = excelBook.getAllPictures();
         if (pics != null) {
             for (int i = 0; i < pics.size(); i++) {
                 Picture pic = (Picture) pics.get (i);
                 try {
                     pic.writeImageContent(new FileOutputStream (ctxPath + pic.suggestFullFileName() ) );
                 } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                     e.printStackTrace();
                 }
             }
         }
         Document htmlDocument = excelToHtmlConverter.getDocument();
         ByteArrayOutputStream outStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
         DOMSource domSource = new DOMSource (htmlDocument);
         StreamResult streamResult = new StreamResult(outStream);
         TransformerFactory tf = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
         Transformer serializer = tf.newTransformer();
         serializer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.ENCODING, "UTF-8");
         serializer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");
         serializer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.METHOD, "html");
         serializer.transform (domSource, streamResult);
         outStream.close();

        OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(new File(ctxPath, htmlid+".html"));
        final PrintStream printStream = new PrintStream(os);
        printStream.print(new String(outStream.toByteArray()));
        printStream.close();
    }
```

Comment: if you print import block, my life would be better)) I really miss it. List of jars is not enought

Answer (score 0):

Check http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/poi/trunk/src/examples/src/org/apache/poi/ss/examples/html/

You need to include the classes and style sheet in your project. You can refactor and change the packages names to your project package names.

Also you can change the styles in the CSS file "excelStyle.css" to change the colors of the output HTMLs.

Comment: I get compile error in those classes? How do i resolve them?

Answer (score 0):

I'm leaving this example using `ExcelToHtmlConverter()` here because I couldn't find one anywhere when I was searching for the same thing.

```
HSSFWorkbook excelDoc = ExcelToHtmlUtils.loadXls(inputDocument);

ExcelToHtmlConverter converter = new ExcelToHtmlConverter(
    DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder().newDocument()
);

converter.processWorkbook(excelDoc);

Document htmlDoc = converter.getDocument();
ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
DOMSource domSource = new DOMSource(htmlDoc);
StreamResult streamResult = new StreamResult(out);
TransformerFactory transfFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
Transformer serializer = transfFactory.newTransformer();

serializer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.ENCODING, "UTF-8");
serializer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");
serializer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.METHOD, "html");
serializer.transform(domSource, streamResult);

out.close();

String result = new String(out.toByteArray());
```

Hope this helps some of you.

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand the first question. In terms of libraries, the only external dependency is Apache POI, specifically [this one](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.poi/poi/3.17). As far as how exactly it works, if it were, say a separate method, it would take in a `File` object, in this example called `inputDocument` and the resulting HTML code is generated and saved in the `result` variable.