# Convert Excel file to MHTML using Java API

Tags: java, html, excel, apache-poi, mhtml

How to Convert Excel file to MHTML using Java API open source ?

I have requirement to publish a excel file in J2ee web application , direct viewing of excel is not possible without downloading , so i am trying it to convert to MHTML first and display it in web browser .

Answer (score 1):

1. [convert the Excel to HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9740215/convert-excel-spreadsheets-to-html-using-the-apache-poi-library)
2. [combine the html and the other resources to a MHTML with the help of javamail](http://petr.pudlak.name/dw/blog:2011:0611_constructing_mhtml_files_in_java_using_javamail_api)