# How to use apache POI to convert a sheet page with shapes to a picture or HTML?

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

Here I have some excel files, I want to convert the sheets which containing shapes to images. But unforturnately, there is no interface support such a function. Shape is different with images, they are vector, I can only get some information about text or math. I cannot get their byte value or render them on an image or HTML file. If I convert the excel to pdf, the shape will be damaged in different degrees. I have try this for near a month, and searched a lot about it. But nothing can satisfy such a requirement. 
What should I do just to make it?

This is the code asking for help.

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public static void xlsToImage(HSSFSheet sheet,String userAccount) {
    HSSFPatriarch hp = sheet.getDrawingPatriarch();
    List<HSSFShape> shapes = hp.getChildren();
    if(shapes.size() > 0) {// I need help from here. 
        for(HSSFShape hssfShape : shapes)
        {
            hssfShape.getAnchor().getDx1();
        }
    }
}
```

This is the code to convert an excel file to pdf file.

```
public class Test {

/**
 * 获取license
 * 
 * @return
 */
public static boolean getLicense() {
    boolean result = false;
    try {
        InputStream is = Test.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("\\license.xml");
        License aposeLic = new License();
        aposeLic.setLicense(is);
        result = true;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return result;
}

/**
 * 支持DOC, DOCX, OOXML, RTF, HTML, OpenDocument, PDF, EPUB, XPS, SWF等相互转换<br>
 * 
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // 验证License
    if (!getLicense()) {
        return;
    }

    try {
        long old = System.currentTimeMillis();
        Workbook wb = new Workbook("C:\\Users\\Administrator\\Desktop\\1.逻辑结构图-灾备.xls");// 原始excel路径
        File pdfFile = new File("C:\\Users\\Administrator\\Desktop\\test2.pdf");// 输出路径
        FileOutputStream fileOS = new FileOutputStream(pdfFile);

        wb.save(fileOS, SaveFormat.PDF);

        long now = System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.println("共耗时：" + ((now - old) / 1000.0) + "秒");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

Any answer will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please try to have a look https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31937106/convert-ms-excel-worksheet-to-image

Comment: @SaviNuclear Thank you a lot, it works. Tho' the polylines are all converted to straight lines in the picture.

Comment: Good to know that

Answer (score 0):

**Required jar**
poi-3.17.jar
poi-examples-3.17.jar
poi-excelant-3.17.jar
poi-ooxml-3.17.jar
poi-ooxml-schemas-3.15.0.jar
dom4j-1.6.1.jar
poi-scratchpad-3.17.jar
xmlbeans-2.6.0.jar

```
/**
* filetype
*/


if("DOC".equals(filetype)){
FileUtil.folderfilehtml(ctxPath + filelocalname, zid, ctxPath);
}else if("XLS".equals(filetype)||"XLSX".equals(filetype)){
FileUtil.folderfileExceltohtml(ctxPath + filelocalname, zid, ctxPath);
}else if("PDF".equals(filetype)){
FileUtil.pdf2html("C:\\application\\pdf2htmlEX-v1.0\\pdf2htmlEX.exe",ctxPath + filelocalname,application.getRealPath("/")+DOWNLOADPATH.get("folderpdf"),zid+".html");
}else if("PPT".equals(filetype)){
FileUtil.pptToHtml(ctxPath + filelocalname, zid, ctxPath,webpath);
}


/**
 * word to HTML
 * 
*/
    public static void folderfilehtml(String filename, String htmlid, String ctxPath) throws IOException, ParserConfigurationException, TransformerException{
        InputStream input = new FileInputStream(filename);
        HWPFDocument wordDocument = new HWPFDocument(input);
        WordToHtmlConverter wordToHtmlConverter = new WordToHtmlConverter(
        DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder()
          .newDocument());
        wordToHtmlConverter.setPicturesManager(new PicturesManager() {
         public String savePicture(byte[] content, PictureType pictureType,
           String suggestedName, float widthInches, float heightInches) {
          return suggestedName;
         }
        });
        wordToHtmlConverter.processDocument(wordDocument);
        List pics = wordDocument.getPicturesTable().getAllPictures();
        if (pics != null) {
         for (int i = 0; i < pics.size(); i++) {
          Picture pic = (Picture) pics.get(i);
          try {
           pic.writeImageContent(new FileOutputStream(ctxPath
             + pic.suggestFullFileName()));
          } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
          }
         }
        }
        Document htmlDocument = wordToHtmlConverter.getDocument();
        ByteArrayOutputStream outStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        DOMSource domSource = new DOMSource(htmlDocument);
        StreamResult streamResult = new StreamResult(outStream);
        TransformerFactory tf = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
        Transformer serializer = tf.newTransformer();
        serializer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.ENCODING, "GB2312");
        serializer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");
        serializer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.METHOD, "html");
        serializer.transform(domSource, streamResult);
        outStream.close();
        String content = new String(outStream.toByteArray());
        String conut =content.substring(0,content.lastIndexOf("</head>"));
        String countend=content.substring(content.indexOf("</head>")-1,content.length()); 
        conut+="<input type="+"button"+" value="+"Print"+" href="+"javascript:void(0);"+" onclick="+"window.print();"+"  class="+"noprint"+" style="+"height:30px;width: 60px; padding-right:5px;align:right;float:left;FONT-WEIGHT: bold;FONT-SIZE: 12pt;COLOR: #000000;FONT-FAMILY: Arial"+">";
        content=conut+countend;
        FileUtils.writeStringToFile(new File(ctxPath, htmlid+".html"), content);
    }
    /**
     * Excel to HTML
     * 
     */
    public static void folderfileExceltohtml(String filename, String htmlid, String ctxPath) throws IOException, ParserConfigurationException, TransformerException{
        InputStream input=new FileInputStream(filename);
         HSSFWorkbook excelBook=new HSSFWorkbook(input);
         ExcelToHtmlConverter excelToHtmlConverter = new ExcelToHtmlConverter (DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder().newDocument() );
         excelToHtmlConverter.processWorkbook(excelBook);
         List pics = excelBook.getAllPictures();
         if (pics != null) {
             for (int i = 0; i < pics.size(); i++) {
                 Picture pic = (Picture) pics.get (i);
                 try {
                     pic.writeImageContent (new FileOutputStream (ctxPath + pic.suggestFullFileName() ) );
                 } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                     e.printStackTrace();
                 }
             }
         }
         Document htmlDocument =excelToHtmlConverter.getDocument();
         ByteArrayOutputStream outStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
         DOMSource domSource = new DOMSource (htmlDocument);
         StreamResult streamResult = new StreamResult (outStream);
         TransformerFactory tf = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
         Transformer serializer = tf.newTransformer();
         serializer.setOutputProperty (OutputKeys.ENCODING, "GB2312");
         serializer.setOutputProperty (OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");
         serializer.setOutputProperty (OutputKeys.METHOD, "html");
         serializer.transform (domSource, streamResult);
         outStream.close();

         String content = new String (outStream.toByteArray() );
         String conut =content.substring(0,content.lastIndexOf("</head>"));
         String countend=content.substring(content.indexOf("</head>")-1,content.length()); 
         conut+="<input type="+"button"+" value="+"打印"+" href="+"javascript:void(0);"+" onclick="+"window.print();"+"  class="+"noprint"+" style="+"height:30px;width: 60px; padding-right:5px;align:right;float:left;FONT-WEIGHT: bold;FONT-SIZE: 12pt;COLOR: #000000;FONT-FAMILY: Arial"+">";
         content=conut+countend;
         FileUtils.writeStringToFile(new File (ctxPath, htmlid+".html"), content);
    }

    /**
     * PDF to HTML
     */

    /** 
     * @param ises 
     * @return 
     * @throws IOException 
     */  
    /**
     * 
     * @param exeFilePath
     * @param pdfFile
     * @param [destDir] 
     * @param htmlName
     * @return
     */
    public static boolean pdf2html(String exeFilePath, String pdfFile,
            String destDir, String htmlFileName) {
        if (!(exeFilePath != null && !"".equals(exeFilePath) && pdfFile != null
                && !"".equals(pdfFile) && htmlFileName != null && !""
                    .equals(htmlFileName))) {
            System.out.println("传递的参数有误！");
            return false;
        }
        Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
        StringBuilder command = new StringBuilder();
        command.append(exeFilePath).append(" ");
        if (destDir != null && !"".equals(destDir.trim()))
            command.append("--dest-dir ").append(destDir.replace(" ", "\" \""))
                    .append(" ");
        command.append("--optimize-text 1 ");
        command.append("--zoom 1.4 ");
        command.append("--process-outline 0 ");
        command.append("--font-format woff ");
                                                // ttf,otf,woff,svg
        command.append(pdfFile.replace(" ", "\" \"")).append(" ");
        if (htmlFileName != null && !"".equals(htmlFileName.trim())) {
            command.append(htmlFileName);
            if (htmlFileName.indexOf(".html") == -1)
                command.append(".html");
        }
        try {
            Process p = rt.exec(command.toString());
            StreamGobbler errorGobbler = new StreamGobbler(p.getErrorStream(),
                    "ERROR");

            errorGobbler.start();
            StreamGobbler outGobbler = new StreamGobbler(p.getInputStream(),
                    "STDOUT");

            outGobbler.start();
            int w = p.waitFor();
            int v = p.exitValue();
            if (w == 0 && v == 0) {
                return true;
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return false;
    }

    public static boolean pdf2html_linux(String pdfFile, String destDir,
            String htmlFileName) {
        if (!(pdfFile != null && !"".equals(pdfFile) && htmlFileName != null && !""
                .equals(htmlFileName))) {
            System.out.println("传递的参数有误！");
            return false;
        }
        Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
        StringBuilder command = new StringBuilder();
        command.append("pdf2htmlEX").append(" ");
        if (destDir != null && !"".equals(destDir.trim()))
            command.append("--dest-dir ").append(destDir.replace(" ", "\" \""))
                    .append(" ");
        command.append("--optimize-text 1 ");
        command.append("--process-outline 0 ");
        command.append("--font-format woff ");
                                                // ttf,otf,woff,svg
        command.append(pdfFile.replace(" ", "\" \"")).append(" ");
        if (htmlFileName != null && !"".equals(htmlFileName.trim())) {
            command.append(htmlFileName);
            if (htmlFileName.indexOf(".html") == -1)
                command.append(".html");
        }
        try {
            Process p = rt.exec(command.toString());
            StreamGobbler errorGobbler = new StreamGobbler(p.getErrorStream(),
                    "ERROR");

            errorGobbler.start();
            StreamGobbler outGobbler = new StreamGobbler(p.getInputStream(),
                    "STDOUT");

            outGobbler.start();
            int w = p.waitFor();
            int v = p.exitValue();
            if (w == 0 && v == 0) {
                return true;
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return false;
    }
    /**
     * PPT to HTML
     * @param path
     * @param filename
     * @return
     */
    public static void pptToHtml(String sourcePath, String id, String targetDir,String webpath) {
        File pptFile = new File(sourcePath);
        if (pptFile.exists()) {
            try {
                String type = com.util.FileUtils.GetFileExt(sourcePath);
                if ("ppt".equals(type)) {
                    String htmlStr = toImage2003(sourcePath, targetDir,id,webpath);
                    com.util.FileUtils.writeFile(htmlStr, targetDir + "\\"+id+".html");
                } else if ("pptx".equals(type)) {
                    String htmlStr = toImage2007(sourcePath, targetDir, id,webpath);
                    com.util.FileUtils.writeFile(htmlStr, targetDir + "\\"+id+".html");
                } else {
                    System.out.println("the file is not a ppt");
                }

            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else {
            System.out.println("file does not exist!");
        }

    }

    public static String toImage2007(String sourcePath, String targetDir, String pptFileName, String webpath) throws Exception {
        String htmlStr = "";
        FileInputStream is = new FileInputStream(sourcePath);
        XMLSlideShow ppt = new XMLSlideShow(is);
        is.close();
        com.util.FileUtils.createDir(targetDir);// create html dir
        Dimension pgsize = ppt.getPageSize();
        System.out.println(pgsize.width + "--" + pgsize.height);

        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
        for (int i = 0; i < ppt.getSlides().size(); i++) {
            try {
                // 防止中文乱码
                for (XSLFShape shape : ppt.getSlides().get(i).getShapes()) {
                    if (shape instanceof XSLFTextShape) {
                        XSLFTextShape tsh = (XSLFTextShape) shape;
                        for (XSLFTextParagraph p : tsh) {
                            for (XSLFTextRun r : p) {
                                r.setFontFamily("宋体");
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                BufferedImage img = new BufferedImage(pgsize.width, pgsize.height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
                Graphics2D graphics = img.createGraphics();
                // clear the drawing area
                graphics.setPaint(Color.white);
                graphics.fill(new Rectangle2D.Float(0, 0, pgsize.width, pgsize.height));
                // render
                ppt.getSlides().get(i).draw(graphics);
                // save the output
                String imageDir = targetDir + pptFileName + "\\";
                com.util.FileUtils.createDir(imageDir);// create image dir
                String imagePath = imageDir + pptFileName + "-" + (i + 1) + ".png";
                String imagewebpath = webpath+pptFileName+"\\"+ pptFileName + "-" + (i + 1) + ".png";
                sb.append("<html>");
                sb.append("<body>");
                sb.append("<input type=button value=Print  href="+"javascript:void(0);"+" onclick="+"window.print();"+"  class="+"noprint"+" style="+"height:30px;width: 60px; padding-right:5px;align:right;float:left;FONT-WEIGHT: bold;FONT-SIZE: 12pt;COLOR: #000000;FONT-FAMILY: Arial"+">");
                sb.append("<br />");
                sb.append("<p style=text-align:center;>");
                sb.append("<img src=" + "\"" + imagewebpath + "\"" + "/>");
                sb.append("</p>");
                sb.append("<br />");
                sb.append("</html>");
                sb.append("</body>");
                FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(imagePath);
                javax.imageio.ImageIO.write(img, "png", out);
                out.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("第" + i + "张ppt转换出错");
            }
        }
        System.out.println("success");
        htmlStr = sb.toString();

        return htmlStr;
    }


    public static String toImage2003(String sourcePath, String targetDir, String pptFileName,String webpath) {
        String htmlStr = "";
        try {
            HSLFSlideShow ppt = new HSLFSlideShow(new HSLFSlideShowImpl(sourcePath));
            com.util.FileUtils.createDir(targetDir);// create html dir
            Dimension pgsize = ppt.getPageSize();
            StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
            for (int i = 0; i < ppt.getSlides().size(); i++) {
                // 防止中文乱码
                for (HSLFShape shape : ppt.getSlides().get(i).getShapes()) {
                    if (shape instanceof HSLFTextShape) {
                        HSLFTextShape tsh = (HSLFTextShape) shape;
                        for (HSLFTextParagraph p : tsh) {
                            for (HSLFTextRun r : p) {
                                r.setFontFamily("宋体");
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                BufferedImage img = new BufferedImage(pgsize.width, pgsize.height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
                Graphics2D graphics = img.createGraphics();
                // clear the drawing area
                graphics.setPaint(Color.white);
                graphics.fill(new Rectangle2D.Float(0, 0, pgsize.width, pgsize.height));
                // render
                ppt.getSlides().get(i).draw(graphics);
                String imageDir = targetDir + pptFileName + "\\";
                com.util.FileUtils.createDir(imageDir);// create image dir
                String imagePath = imageDir + pptFileName + "-" + (i + 1) + ".png";
                String imagewebpath = webpath +pptFileName+"\\"+ pptFileName + "-" + (i + 1) + ".png";
                sb.append("<html>");
                sb.append("<body>");
                sb.append("<input type="+"button"+" value="+"Print"+" href="+"javascript:void(0);"+" onclick="+"window.print();"+"  class="+"noprint"+" style="+"height:30px;width: 60px; padding-right:5px;align:right;float:left;FONT-WEIGHT: bold;FONT-SIZE: 12pt;COLOR: #000000;FONT-FAMILY: Arial"+">");
                sb.append("<br />");
                sb.append("<p style=text-align:center;>");
                sb.append("<img src=" + "\"" + imagewebpath + "\"" + "/>");
                sb.append("</p>");
                sb.append("<br />");
                sb.append("</html>");
                sb.append("</body>");
                FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(imagePath);
                javax.imageio.ImageIO.write(img, "png", out);
                out.close();
            }
            System.out.println("success");
            htmlStr = sb.toString();
        } catch (Exception e) {

        }
        return htmlStr;
    }
```